# Fix Query Display Row With The Last ID With SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have row table like this :

```
ID      EQ  TI      LE  VAL     NO
==================================
1504    TX  410413  Y   2065000 1
1504    TX  410413  Y   2065000 2
1504    TX  410413  Y   2065000 3
1504    TX  410413  Y   730000  4
1504    TX  410413  C   2606900 5
1504    TX  410413  Y   4120900 6
1504    TX  410413  Y   4120900 7
1504    TX  410413  Y   2065000 8
1504    TX  410413  Y   2065000 9
1503    TX  410413  Y   2065000 1
1503    TX  410413  Y   2065000 2
1503    TX  410413  Y   2065000 3
1503     TX 410413  Y   2065000 4
1503    TX  410413  C   2606900 5
1503    TX  410413  Y   4120900 6
1503    TX  410413  Y   4120900 7
1503    TX  410413  Y   2065000 8
1503    TX  410413  Y   2065000 9
```

What i want to ask is, how to display rows only with the latest id (1504). The situation is i dont know the latest id so, query like select * from ... where id LIKE '1504' is not i want to use.

Please give me any advice query how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Select * from yourtable where id=(select max(id) from yourtable)
```

You can use in if you want to display multiple ids.

Comment: with little modification tu suit my case, your solution is works. Thanks Tim3880